# Eclipse Plugin: added new item to right-click popup menu, how can the file name/path be determined?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

The ExecutionEvent in the execute method which is triggered when the new item is selected on the menu does not seem to refer to the file that was right clicked on. I wonder if I need to add listener for this and if so will this interfere with the execution method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get in the event is the current selection which may be a file or may be something else depending on how you defined the menu 'enabledWhen'. You can get the file from the selection.

```
IStructuredSelection selection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentStructuredSelection(event);

if (!selection.isEmpty()) {
  IFile file = Adapters.adapt(selection.getFirstElement(), IFile.class, true);

  if (file != null) {
      ... your code
  }
}
```

In some cases an adapter to `IFile` is not available but one to `IResource` is. In this case use:

```
IResource resource = Adapters.adapt(selection.getFirstElement(), IResource.class);
if (resource instanceof IFile) {
  IFile file = (IFile)resource;

}
```

Note: `getCurrentStructuredSelection` and `Adapters` are relatively new APIs. In older versions of Eclipse you will need slightly more complicated code.

`HandlerUtil` is `org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil` in the `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` plug-in, `Adapters` is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Adapters`

Comment: 1. I am surprised one can't get the name directly from a method on event 2. I see that the class of the first element is compilation unit but i don't know how to get the jar for this -- I am guessing that is why the Adapter is used but i get null for the file when I try what you suggested.

Comment: I get now that because it is in fact a compilation unit is why the file was null.

Comment: I think I am having trouble with the correct plugin dependencies: the specific class of the firstElement is org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit although there is another CompilationUnit class that was suggested by the compiler. Can you tell me how to add to plugin dependencies so this works?

Comment: `CompilationUnit` is an internal class so you should not try to use it. In this case you can adapt to `IResource` and check that it is an instanceof  `IFile` - see updated answer.